# docker: invalid reference format with own registry with basic AU

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I can see my docker registry by

```
curl -X GET "https://mylogin:mypass@myregistry.mydomain.io:myport/v2/_catalog"
```

or

```
curl -X GET "https://mylogin:mypass@myregistry.mydomain.io:myport/v2/myimage/manifests/latest"
```

but if I start container

```
sudo docker run -it https://mylogin:mypass@myregistry.mydomain.io:myport/myimage:latest
```

I receive error

```
docker: invalid reference format
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> https://mylogin:mypass@myregistry.mydomain.io:myport/myimage:latest
> ```

To login to your registry server, first run:

```
docker login myregistry.mydomain.io
```

Then pull the image with:

```
docker pull myregistry.mydomain.io:myport/myimage:latest
```

There should be no `https://` or user credentials in the image name you pull.