# How to pull docker image from ECR in Githubactions

Tags: docker, github-actions, amazon-ecr, building-github-actions

I'm trying to pull docker image from ECR and deploy it on ec2 instance. However it's throwing an error like

```
docker pull  $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG

======END======
err: invalid reference format
2022/11/03 15:31:54 Process exited with status 1
```

My yml file is:

```
name: Docker Image CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:

  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.TF_USER_AWS_KEY }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.TF_USER_AWS_SECRET }}
        aws-region: us-east-1

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: githubactions
        IMAGE_TAG: githubactions_image
      run: |
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG .
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
    - name: Docker pull & run from github
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: ec2-3-86-102-151.compute-1.amazonaws.com
        username: ec2-user
        key: ${{ secrets.ACTIONS_PRIVATE_KEY }}
        envs: GITHUB_SHA
        script: |
            docker pull  $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
```

I spent a lot of time and I can't really understand what's wrong. Any idea really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is with the env vars. You are confusing the GitHub server to the ec2 server.

The env var you mention in the GitHub YAML do no exist on the remote machine (ec2). The cmd `docker pull  $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG` is failing because the remote machine (ec2) do not know about your GitHub env vars.

From the [docs here](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action) you can see that there is an easy built-in way to pass it to the ec2 instance:

```
  - name: pass environment
    uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
+   env:
+     FOO: "BAR"
+     BAR: "FOO"
+     SHA: ${{ github.sha }}
    with:
      host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
      username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
      key: ${{ secrets.KEY }}
      port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
+     envs: FOO,BAR,SHA
      script: |
        echo "I am $FOO"
        echo "I am $BAR"
        echo "sha: $SHA"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first add an ls and echo:

```yaml
      run: |
        pwd
        ls -arth
        echo "docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG ."
        docker ...
```

That way, I would check if I am in the right folder (with a `Dockerfile` in it), and if all variables are indeed valued.

If you see `<aregistry>/<arepo>:` (meaning no tag), the final '`:`' might be enough to trigger the error message.
That or:

- the name use the wrong hyphen '`-`' as [in this issue](https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/3250).
- the image name has an [invalid character like a `\`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73022523/6309)
- the image name uses [the wrong syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73886891/6309)

Comment: Here dockerfile is there on my github repo and for that repo trying to build and push to ECR. And later need to deploy on new EC2 instance.

Comment: @Vamsi OK, what does the echo show?

Comment: out: docker build -t /: .

Comment: @Vamsi So your variables are empty, which explains the error message.

Comment: Yes..How can i use/define variable already define in the jobs section(        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }})

Comment: without using export ECR_REGISTRY="***.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" command

Comment: @Vamsi [Check first](https://github.com/aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login#troubleshooting) why `steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry` is empty

Comment: It's not empty...it's a URI of ECR repo
    ECR_REGISTRY: ***.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com